# Is it acceptable to state in an interview that the work you've done at your previous job left you feeling unfulfilled?

Tags: interviewing, united-states, work-experience, insurance

I currently work in the insurance industry handling claims and at times I feel like the work is both too easy and unfulfilling. Now after browsing this site and seeing questions regarding if you should bad mouth your previous employer I was wondering if it was acceptable to mention how performing a previous job made you feel. As of this writing I'm not planning on quitting but I know the question of "why did you leave your previous occupation" always comes up so I was curious if feelings about the work that you did were acceptable to mention even if they are negative. Or is it best left unsaid?

Comment: @JMERCIKS, First, "Do not say any thing NEGATIVE about your old company, old boss, old coworkers, and old position" because if you do, then the interviewers may think that you are negative person who may treat your new company the same way. Second, in the new interviews, simply mention that you want to seek new challenges, broaden your views and technical skills, etc...

Comment: Note that different people will consider different things fulfilling. In particular, some people consider solving a challenging problem to be fulfilling, while some other people consider solving an important problem to be fulfilling. Maybe your previous job was "very important but too easy". Be careful what words you use.

Comment: Well, it would seem rather silly to say "Because I am 100% happy with my current job." as a reason for wanting to leave it.

Answer (score 12):

As long as you make the separation about you and not about your previous (or current) employer, you'll be fine. As you're describing it, you're seeking more fulfillment in your work. You just need to be able to define what that fulfillment looks like for you. It shouldn't reference any part of why it's not fulfilling in your current or previous role. It should indicate why it WOULD be fulfilling at the new company.

Keep the conversation centered around you pursuing your own advancement of goals and fulfillment, and avoid anything that says the previous company is denying that to you (even if it's true). Sometimes companies just don't have opportunities for folks to advance themselves, and it's ok to leave it at that.

Comment: Yes, this exactly. Frame every answer in an interview positively, as "I'm looking for _x_".

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the new job is doing.

If you apply for a job doing exactly the same work and say you're unfulfilled in the interview then the interviewer should be concerned. After all, if you find yourself unfulfilled packing widgets for OldCompany, why should you find packing widgets fulfilling at NewCompany?

If the work is something different then it's pretty easy to spin that in a way that is positive. Say you find your current role unfulfilling but you've been doing something relevant to the new job and find that very interesting, and that's why you applied for the job.

But, don't say anything too negative. You can say you're not interested in your current role packing widgets, but don't say it's because your manager is a jerk, the company is being run by a moron and your colleagues are all assholes.

Something else you touch on is that you don't need to tell them unless they ask. If the interviewer wants to know this kind of thing they should ask. You don't need to volunteer information that could be detrimental to you.

Answer (score 0):

As a guiding principle, with very few exceptions - you should never trash your previous employment.

If you want to show difference - praise new / potential place as new horizon, aligned with your current goals, place where you can grow personally and professionally etc